# ausearch how to specify both time and date

Tags: date, timestamps, linux-audit

I can run `ausearch` based on time:

```
sudo ausearch --start '16:48:07'
```

or date:

```
sudo ausearch --start '05/07/2019'
```

but not both:

```
> sudo ausearch --start '05/07/2019 16:48:07'
Invalid start time (05/07/2019 16:48:07). Hour, Minute, and Second are required.
```

The man page clearly implies that you can specify date or time or both but does not have an example with both.

How does one run `ausearch` with both date and time specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date and time should be separate arguments:

```
sudo ausearch --start 05/07/2019 '16:48:07'
```

I found [an example online](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2012-June/msg00001.html), but a more careful reader could have seen this in [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ausearch):

```
       -ts, --start [start-date] [start-time]
              Search for events with time stamps equal to or after  the  given
              start  time. The format of start time depends on your locale. If
              the date is omitted, today is assumed. If the time  is  omitted,
              midnight is assumed. Use 24 hour clock time rather than AM or PM
              to specify time. An example date using the en_US.utf8 locale  is
              09/03/2009.  An  example  of  time  is 18:00:00. The date format
              accepted is influenced by the LC_TIME environmental variable.
```

Notice `-ts, --start [start-date] [start-time]`, clearly there are two optional arguments, not one.

Comment: Thank you very much!